# Error playing video with MPMovieViewController on iOS6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MPMoviePlayerViewController Generating lots of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224476/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-generating-lots-of-errors)

I am trying to play a movie using MPMovieViewController on iOS6 and am getting the following messages in my console:

```
Nov  1 17:44:19 Kamrans-MacBook-Pro.local HoosierAgToday[58188] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Nov  1 17:44:19 Kamrans-MacBook-Pro.local HoosierAgToday[58188] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Nov  1 17:44:19 Kamrans-MacBook-Pro.local HoosierAgToday[58188] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Nov  1 17:44:19 Kamrans-MacBook-Pro.local HoosierAgToday[58188] <Error>: CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x0
Nov  1 17:44:19 Kamrans-MacBook-Pro.local HoosierAgToday[58188] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
2012-11-01 17:44:19.412 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-11-01 17:44:19.412 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-11-01 17:44:19.422 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-11-01 17:44:19.630 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-11-01 17:44:19.634 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2012-11-01 17:44:19.635 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2012-11-01 17:44:19.637 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-11-01 17:44:19.638 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2012-11-01 17:44:19.646 HoosierAgToday[58188:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

When I try to play it from this URL: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 it works. When I downloaded this exact file and put it on our server http://loadoutnews.co/hat/default/download/post.videoios.afa1cc6b18aa0e03.6269675f6275636b5f62756e6e792e6d7034.mp4 it doesn't work properly and gives me these errors. I made sure the URL is valid and properly % escaped if it needed to be as well. This is the code I have to play the video:

```
//video 5
        NSDictionary *dict = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *escapedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://loadoutnews.co/hat/default/download/",[dict objectForKey:@"videoios"]];
        escapedValue = [escapedValue stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedValue]];
        [player.view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
        [self presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
        //I have tried it with and without this line below
        [player.moviePlayer play];
        [player release];
```

I find it weird that it does play the video on the initial link given, but not on our server. If you goto the link I sent, the video file is valid and is the same one...I don't understand why it won't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am having very similar problems!

Comment: A friend of mine figured it out. It had to do with the server sending improper headers and what not. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: yes that would be great actually!