# why MPMoviePlayerController show these messages only in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MPMoviePlayerViewController Generating lots of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224476/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-generating-lots-of-errors)

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play local videos. The app works well in iPad, but it will log out some messages only in iPhone though it also works well. What does these messages mean? And i wonder whether it will be rejected by apple store if i publish it?

Log is like this:

```
2013-01-30 10:25:49.586 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-01-30 10:25:49.587 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:49.590 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-01-30 10:25:49.591 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:49.615 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:49.623 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2013-01-30 10:25:49.624 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2013-01-30 10:25:49.625 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2013-01-30 10:25:49.626 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2013-01-30 10:25:49.628 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:49.649 XX[1744:907] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2013-01-30 10:25:50.193 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1
2013-01-30 10:25:50.195 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:50.198 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
2013-01-30 10:25:59.513 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-01-30 10:25:59.514 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:59.516 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-30 10:25:59.628 XX[1744:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 1 -> 1
```

Comment: Do you have `[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];` added? If not, try adding that and check.

Comment: @ACB i tried once, but it seems it doesn't work. the log is still the same.

Comment: @chancy: I got these messages on iPad simulator and iPad device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also getting these errors but besides these errors my video is playing fine with this

player.I think there is no solution for it. If your video is working fine then ignore these

warnings or errors. see my answer in this link: [MPMoviePlayerViewController Generating lots of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224476/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-generating-lots-of-errors/14228396#14228396)

Comment: yes, i see. in your app also only these messages are shown in iPhone?

Comment: Yes, its only see when I run my app on IPhone or sometimes on device also...

Comment: My this app is also on app store but there is no issue in this app so don't worry about these warnings...